# Be accurate within 0.2 of a percent using gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, gamma-distribution

Carrying out enough simulations of an experiment in gamma distribution, how can I find an answer to be accurate to within 0.2 of a percent. (my answer is in the form of a percentage)

Comment: Possibly this is a question for the mathematics site. Although having `r`in Stack Overflow as a well-followed tag does present overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation of the mean is estimated using `sigma / sqrt(N)` where sigma is the standard deviation of your sample and `N` the number of elements in your sample.

(The nature of the underlying distribution does not matter).

Use this to compute the value of `N` required to fit the standard deviation of the mean to be 0.2%.